# How to add custom naming to Alexa Custom Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have intent CreateNewDogIntent.

The following is the dialog flow that I would like to implement.

```
U: Alexa, tell Dog Creator to create a new medium dog named Barky.
U: Alexa, tell Dog Creator to create a new large dog named Barky.
```

or

```
U: Alexa, tell Dog Creator to create a new dog.
A: What would you like your dog to be named?
U: Barky
```

I want the name to be any possible value.
Is this possible to implement with Alexa custom skills kit?
From what I understand, I would need to create a slot type for name value, but there is no option to create a "catch all" type, with exception of SearchQuery which can only be used without any other slot type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "catch all" slot type.
I faced a similar problem when implementing some word games, I needed a slot type where every word would be caught.
What I did is to put together a slot type with 20 thousands words.
If the user says one of them, all good.
If the word is not in the slot type but it is considered similar to those in the slot type, it will go to your backend with a flag [ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/cfbd2f5e-c72f-4b03-8040-8628bbca204c/alexa-skill-teardown-understanding-entity-resolution-with-pet-match). You might want to keep those to enhance your slop type.
On top of that, the [FallbackIntent](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2018/07/use-the-new-fallback-intent-to-respond-gracefully-to-unexpected-customer-requests) will allow you to respond gracefully to "uncatchable" words.